# Angular select default value with ngModel not working on a select element but working on another

Tags: angular, ngmodel

why is this working:

myComponent1.html

```
    <select  id="BisMonat" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="currentmonatbis">
    <option [value]="01">Januar</option>
    <option [value]="02">Februar</option>
    <option [value]="03">März</option>
    <option [value]="04">April</option>
    <option [value]="05">Mai</option>
    <option [value]="06">Juni</option>
    <option [value]="07">Juli</option>
    <option [value]="08">August</option>
    <option [value]="09">September</option>
    <option [value]="10">Oktober</option>
    <option [value]="11">November</option>
    <option [value]="12">Dezember</option>
    </select>
```

myComponent1.ts:

```
export class myComponent1 implements OnInit
{
  currentmonatbis: number = new Date().getMonth()+1;
```

but this is not working:

myComponent2.html:

```
 <select  id="Weltanschauung" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="weltanschauung">
  <option [value]="westlich">Westlich</option>
  <option [value]="koscher">Koscher</option>
  <option [value]="halal">Halāl</option>
  <option [value]="vegetarisch">Vegetarisch</option>
  <option [value]="vegan">Vegan</option>
</select>
```

myComponent2.ts:

```
export class myComponent2.ts implements OnInit
{
  weltanschauung: string = "koscher";
```

like its basically the same ??

Comment: Can u provide stackblitz ex?

Comment: because `new Date().getMonth()+1;` will return 1 or 2 or 3... but your value is 01, 02, 03 and so on.

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth you missed the point. Thats the select thats working the otherone is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [value]="westlich", The compiler is searching for a variable named "westlich" but there is no variable like this.
Use this:

```html
 <select  id="Weltanschauung" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="weltanschauung">
  <option value="westlich">Westlich</option>
  <option value="koscher">Koscher</option>
  <option value="halal">Halāl</option>
  <option value="vegetarisch">Vegetarisch</option>
  <option value="vegan">Vegan</option>
</select>
```

I.E Use the values with the [,]

Comment: Right, example for your answer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttsfd2

Comment: Okey I see but why does the first select with "currentmonatbis" work? there are no variables with "01", "02" and so on either?

Comment: Yes, but the compiler knows that 01 is a number (1) and so on, try to change it to 00001 or something like it and it will work. because it's just a number and not a string

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <select  id="Weltanschauung" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="weltanschauung">
  <option value="westlich">Westlich</option>
  <option value="koscher">Koscher</option>
  <option value="halal">Halāl</option>
  <option value="vegetarisch">Vegetarisch</option>
  <option value="vegan">Vegan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i forgot to import FormsModule & after importing two way binding is working as expected

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';